# Hydrostatics , work Power and Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work, density, fluid-statics

If a servant lifts 10 cubic meter of liquid from a tank, which is at a depth of 40m . If the work done by him is 1600J, then find the density of the liquid (g = 10 m/s^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work is described by the following formula:

$$W=\vec{F} \cdot \vec{s} = F\cdot s \cdot \cos \alpha$$

with $s$ is the distance, 40 m in this case, and $\alpha$ the angle between $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{s}$, which in this case happens to be zero, giving $W = F \cdot s$

$F$ is force, in this case work is done against gravitational force, so

$$F=mg$$

$m$ is the liquid mass and $m=\rho V$

$\rho$ is the liquid's density, $V$ is the liquid's volume.

$$W=\rho Vgs$$ and therefore $$\rho=\frac {W}{Vgs}$$